# TFS 2018 Set Build Task To Only Get a Sub Folder Of The Respository

Tags: git, tfs, build

We have just moved from a TFVC repository to a TFS Git one and I am in the process of moving all of our build definitions to use git. In the build definition, is it possible to set it so that when it gets sources is will get a sub-folder in the repository rather than downloading the entire solution.

For example in the image below to set the Repository to `STARS\Folder1\Folder2`

[image]

Our main repository is large and creating some artifacts does not need the entire solution to be downloaded to our TFS server.

Answer (score 0):

That`s why I like TFVC ))

By default Git clones a whole repository ([How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)).

But you may try [VFS for git tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sander-aernouts.vsts-vfs-for-git-tasks).